# Saving file created from browser to disk - Cannot use new File() on FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox

The following script creates a json file in the browser and automatically save it to disk.

It works fine with `Chrome 50.0.2661.87` m but it **does not work** on `FF 47.0a2` (although no errors are throw).

Issue seems related to (as if you comment it out works):

```
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
```

What is the reasons for this behavior on FF? Should I omit window.URL.revokeObjectURL() at all;

Notes: It should works on the latest browsers Chrome and FireFox.

```js
var saveDataToFile = function(data, fileName, properties) {
  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var file = new File(data, fileName, properties),
    link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
  link.download = fileName;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);// possible problem here
  document.body.removeChild(link)
};

var fileName = 'test.json',
  properties = {
    type: 'octet/stream'
  },
  data = [JSON.stringify({
    test: 'hello'
  })];
saveDataToFile(data, fileName, properties);
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove this line

```
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
```

Seems like you are disposing url before it is used for download.

Test: https://jsfiddle.net/cLvf7yny/

Comment: Thanks for sharing, issue happens only on FF and not Chrome. Any idea why?

Comment: @GibboK, just different implementaition of downloading.